# Runtime permission (requestPermissions) is not working

Tags: android, permissions

I have to check permission in Fragment at the runtime for getting Location.
Here is a function for checking permission.

```
    public void weather() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

    try {
        if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

             requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);

            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            syncData(latitude, longitude);

                        }
                    }
                });
        return;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        weather();
    }
}
```

The issue is that my code stuck in this like a loop. It does not grant permissions and every time this if check return true and my code back and forth like a loop between override permission and if statement. And one thing more do we need this two permssion in the manifest as well?

```
 if (checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

         requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);

        return;
    }
```

Comment: I am quite not sure, can u try by adding ActivityCompat as prefix like ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission and ActivityCompat.requestPermissions and try?

Comment: It's not working... on Android versions lower than Marshmallow!

Comment: @ Raghavendra thank you but I m working in a fragment ,by adding prefix it will go first to the parent class.I think we dont need to do that.am I right?

Comment: @ ModularSynth its android 7 device

Comment: Did you also set the permission request in the Manifest?

Comment: I think you have checked on don’t asked again. That why it goes infinite loop

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan put onRequestPermissionsResult in Activity and try?

Comment: @ ModularSynth basically its working ,it goes to override menthod(onRequestPermissionsResult) so it means it working but not setting the permssion

Comment: Where does the magic number 123 in `if (requestCode == 123) {` come from?

Comment: @M.ArslanKhan Try FragmentCompat.requestPermissions ?

Comment: @ModularSynth YES I have set permission it manifest as well

Comment: use Rxpermission 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:0.7.0@aar'

Comment: @ModularSynth  requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 123);

Comment: remove ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED from condition, and only check ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and request permission

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (grantResults.length == 1 &&
                grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            weather();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Permission denied", oast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below condition in onRequestPermissionsResult

```
if (requestCode == 123 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        weather();
    }
```

And you can remove and condition of `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED`as it belongs to same permission group with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION